# Set figure width to the textwidth of an item inside itemize

Tags: graphics, itemize

I want to include an image that aligns with the text width of an item inside an itemize.

In the example below, if I scale the image down, it pulls away from both sides. I want to easily set the width so the image aligns with the outer edges of the text for the given item it has been placed in.

I know I can use `adjustbox` and right-align the image, but I still have to scale the width manually.

Is it possible to achieve this automatically?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.65in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\section{My Section}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Caption}
            \label{fig:figure}
        \end{figure}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The only purpose of `figure` is to take the content out of the document flow to be an insert, so it carefully hides the current font and indentation to make a normalised full width insert. You can undo that but the most natural thing is to not use `figure` and just  use `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{...}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That was incredibly insightful, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use package `caption` instead of `float`:

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.65in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\section{My Section}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \captionof{figure}{Caption}
            \label{fig:figure}
        \end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]